# excel vba code to export a Microsoft Excel 97-2003 .xls file

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I am trying to open a file from a user specified path using a VBA Function.

When I paste the content of the file to the desired worksheet, it pastes some weird unrecognizable characters in the worksheet. Can anyone figure out what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Sub x_Macro()

'****************Declaring relevant variables****************'

Dim t As Range
Dim path: path = Application.GetOpenFilename("XLS Files (*.xls), *.xls")
Dim cht1 As ChartObject

'Dim button_click As VbMsgBoxResult

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(2).Activate
If path = False Then Exit Sub
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = True
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: `Connection:="TEXT"` - but you are trying to download an Excel file. Either change connection type or convert XLS as Text (or probably CSV) to remove any extraneous formatting.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your comment.
I tried changing the connection type to 'XLS' & 'CSV' but it throws an error:
'Application defined or object-defined error'..
any insight?